# Open an application periodically in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, automator, launchd

I want to open a GUI application (most likely Electron based) periodically on a Mac Book. The period will be configured (daily, hourly etc..) within the application. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous approaches you can take.

## launchd or Third Party Launcher

You can use tools like macOS's built-in [`launchd`](http://www.launchd.info) or third party tools like [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) (which I wrote, so feel free to ask me questions about its use):

[image: DssW Power Manager on macOS]

Power Manager includes a task covering [How to Schedule an Application to Launch on Mac OS X](https://dssw.co.uk/blog/2010-07-28-how-to-schedule-an-application-to-launch-on-mac-os-x/).

#### Prefer `launchd` over `cron`

You probably want to avoid [`cron`](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) because it does not operate in the current user's graphical session. `cron` is good for command line tools and scripts, but less well suited to graphical Mac applications.

As [gidds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/291214/gidds) comments below, this limitation can be worked around using the [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) tool.

### AppleScript and Calendar

A simple AppleScript application combined with a calendar event's Open File as an alarm may be enough. The AppleScript snippet below will open a specified application and bring it to the front:

```
tell application "My Electron Application" to activate
```

These related questions go into specifics:

- [How can I schedule sending the day’s iCal events via email?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29725)
- [Schedule open automator application every days works only one time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274314/schedule-open-automator-application-every-days-works-only-one-time)

Comment: Commands launched from cron can get access to the current user's graphical session using the [`reattach-to-user-namespace`](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) command, available in e.g. [HomeBrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/reattach-to-user-namespace).

Comment: It still works for me on macOS 12.4.

Answer (score 2):

How about an old school bash script, called by `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`?

i.e. in your `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc` you can have:

```
# ...
bash /home/<user>/run.sh &
```

And in your `run.sh` you can sleep in a loop and activate the app.

Answer (score 1):

#### `Launchd` .plist file

You can create a `plist` file that will describe the job to be carried out by `launchd` at intervals you can define in the plist.  There's some terminology that is easiest to learn by just reading another plist file, such as the one I've written below.

Once you've done that, you can move the plist file into `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, which will run the job under your username.

Finally, get the `launchd` daemon to `load` your configuration file, which will start the job:

```
launchctl load chri.sk.launchd.plist
```

From then on, the job specified in the plist file will be carried out at the defined intervals, and will continue being carried out forever, or until you `unload` it:

```
launchctl unload chri.sk.launchd.plist
```

It will launch automatically on every system reboot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>chri.sk.launchd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>TextEdit</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/CK/Documents/launchd.err.txt</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This opens up *TextEdit* every 60 seconds.  [Here](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/launchd-plist-examples-startinterval-startcalendarinterval)'s a pretty useful guide on defining intervals.

Any errors are written to the file path specified by `StandardErrorPath`.

Make the filename and the `label` value the same.  Apple's naming convention recommends using a reverse hostname identifier, but in the absence of a domain name that belongs to you, you could simply use something like `surname.firstname.jobtitle`.

The `launchd.plist` man page defines all the property list keys and explains what they each do.  Go to *Terminal* and type `man launchd.plist`.

#### AppleScript

```
property hour : 3600
property day : 86400
property RunEvery : day
property AppName : "An Application"

on run
    idle
end run

on idle
    tell application named AppName to activate
    return RunEvery
end idle

on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

If you save this AppleScript as a **stay-open** application, and then run it, it will stay open and run the `idle` commands every day.  Currently, to stop this script from continuing, you'd have to terminate it from the dock or *Activity Monitor*.

Comment: The `StartInterval` setting in the plist file will be ignored since setting `KeepAlive` to true causes launchd to continuously run the program.  (Each time the program exits it launched it again.)

Comment: @nmgeek Although this was back in 2018, I remember testing the `.plist` file to make sure it did what I was expecting.  Are you implying that the `StartInterval` key can be taken out completely and, provided that the `KeepAlive` flag is on, there would be no observable difference in how the `.plist` performs ?  If that’s true, what dictates the regular execution of the shell code it contains, which at present would execute every 60 seconds ?  `KeepAlive` doesn’t, as far as I know, doesn’t monitor time.  Or have I got this wrong ?

Comment: I did not test this with KeepAlive set to true.  So I'm not sure it is waiting 60 seconds before relaunching the program.  KeepAlive is telling launchd to *immediately* rerun the program after the program exits. As such, the timing depends upon how long the program takes to run.  If the program runs too quickly, launchd will apply throttling, waiting before relaunching.  The throttling delay is 10 seconds.  So if your program was running every 60 seconds, it must have taken 60 seconds until it exited.

Comment: @nmgeek I've amended the example XML in the above answer.  Thanks for highlighting this.